# Glossary per chapter or section

Tags: glossaries, subdividing

I'm looking for a way of creating glossaries, with the help of `glossaries` package, per chapter or section.

In a particular glossary for section should be only the terms used in this section. If term is used in multiple section - appear in correspondent glossaries.

Example (done with the help of `description` environment, just for an example):

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Shall the glossary of a section (say) only contain items that are defined first in this section, or all items used in this section? (If the former, the glossaries are disjoint...)

Comment: I'm seeking for a way to include only the items which is used in the particular section.

Comment: But a glossary item can be used in several sections, so shall it appear in all corresponding glossaries, or only in the first of them?

Comment: @mafp: if it used - yes, it all corresponding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you don't seem interested in the location list, you could change the location counter to `section` and define a glossary style that checks if the current section is in the location list. You'll probably want to neaten the glossary, but here's an example:¹

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool-base}
\usepackage[counter=section,xindy]{glossaries}

\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{0}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{E}{name={\ensuremath{E}},
 description={energy}}

\newglossaryentry{m}{name={\ensuremath{m}},
  description={mass}}

\newglossaryentry{c}{name={\ensuremath{c}},
  description={speed of light}}

\newglossaryentry{v}{name={\ensuremath{v}},
  description=velocity}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}%
{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\striprelax##1\endstriprelax}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsXsectionXglsnumberformat}[2]{##2}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimR}{,}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \edef\doifinlocation{\noexpand\ifinlocation{\thesection}{##2}}%
    \doifinlocation
    {%
      \item \glossentryname{##1} \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    }%
  }%
}

% \ifinlocation{number}{location list}{body}

\newcommand{\ifinlocation}[3]{%
 \DTLifinlist{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
}

\def\striprelax\relax#1\endstriprelax{#1}

\setglossarystyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample Section}

\printglossary

\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \gls{m}\cdot \gls{c}^2
\end{equation}

\section{Another Section}

\printglossary

\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \frac{\gls{m}\gls{v}^2}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that this uses xindy rather than makeindex to suppress the range formation, which makes it easier to test if the current section is in the list.

The result looks like:

[image: image of document]

Here's an alternative approach that uses [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) with the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package. The entries are now defined in a `.bib` file, for example `syms.bib`:

```
@symbol{E,
 name={\ensuremath{E}},
 description={energy}
}

@symbol{m,
  name={\ensuremath{m}},
  description={mass}
}

@symbol{c,
  name={\ensuremath{c}},
  description={speed of light}
}

@symbol{v,
  name={\ensuremath{v}},
  description={velocity}
}
```

The document code now looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrRecordCounter{section}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={syms}, % entries defined in syms.bib
]

\newcommand{\printsectionglossary}[1][]{%
  \printunsrtglossary*[nonumberlist,#1]{%
    \renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryhandler}[1]{%
     \glsxtrfieldxifinlist{##1}{record.section}{\thesection}
     {\glsxtrunsrtdo{##1}}%
     {}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample Section}

\printsectionglossary

\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \gls{m}\cdot \gls{c}^2
\end{equation}

\section{Another Section}

\printsectionglossary

\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \frac{\gls{m}\gls{v}^2}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before. If you want to use the `hyperref` package then you need to make a minor adjustment to prevent duplicate target names:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrRecordCounter{section}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={syms}, % entries defined in syms.bib
]

\newcommand{\printsectionglossary}[1][]{%
  \printunsrtglossary*[nonumberlist,#1]{%
    \renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryhandler}[1]{%
    \glsxtrfieldxifinlist{##1}{record.section}{\thesection}
    {\glsxtrunsrtdo{##1}}%
    {}%
   }%
   \ifcsundef{theHsection}%
   {%
     \setkeys{printgloss}{targetnameprefix={record.\csuse{thesection}.}}%
   }%
   {%
     \setkeys{printgloss}{targetnameprefix={record.\csuse{theHsection}.}}%
   }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample Section}

\printsectionglossary

\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \gls{m}\cdot \gls{c}^2
\end{equation}

\section{Another Section}

\printsectionglossary

\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \frac{\gls{m}\gls{v}^2}{2}
\end{equation}

\printunsrtglossary
\end{document}
```

This makes `\gls` link to the main (full) glossary at the end of the document.

[image: image of document]

---

¹ The original answer used some now deprecated commands `\glossarystyle` (now `\setglossarystyle`) and `\glossaryentryfield`:

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}%
{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\striprelax##1\endstriprelax}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsXsectionXglsnumberformat}[2]{##2}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimR}{,}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \edef\doifinlocation{\noexpand\ifinlocation{\thesection}{##5}}%
    \doifinlocation
    {%
      \item ##2 ##3%
    }%
  }%
}
```

These should not be used with v4.0 onwards.

Comment: Hi, my gut feeling is that this redefinition of `glossentry` messes with the hyperlink, and that one should use `\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}` instead of just `\glossentryname{##1}` to have the link set properly. Am I right?

Comment: @Clément In this case it's better to have a main glossary for the entire document and only include `\glstarget` in that, so any hyperlinks are directed to the main glossary. If `\glstarget` is included in the per chapter/section glossary it could result in duplicate targets if the same entry is used across difference chapters/sections.