# Automated generation of equation key

Tags: equations, glossaries, automation

I am looking for a way to automatically create the legend for an `equation` (let's say embedded in the `align` environment).

What I'm currently using is a semi automated to fully manual way. Let me explain: The result should look like  this:

[image: img1].

What I am doing to accomplish this requires 3 steps to generate the output shown above:

### 1) Placing equation:

```
\begin{align}  
    \dot{D} = \frac{1-\eta_{Deg,r}}{\tau} \label{eq:deg}  
\end{align}
```

### 2) Defining the corresponding entries in the symbol glossary:

```
\newglossaryentry{sym:deg}{  
type=symbols,  
name={$\dot{D}$},  
description={Prozentuale jährliche Abnahme des Wirkungsgrades},  
user1={\%/a},  
sort=deg  
}  

\newglossaryentry{sym:etadegr}{
type=symbols,
name={$\eta_{Deg,r}$},
description={Verbleibender Wirkungsgrad bezogen auf den ursprünglichen Wirkungsgrad},
user1=\%,
sort=eta deg rest
}

\newglossaryentry{sym:tau}{
type=symbols,
name={$\tau$},
description={Lebenszyklus / Einsatzdauer des betrachteten Systems},
user1=a,
sort=tau
}
```

### 3) Custom command to fill table with glossaries reference:

```
%Command
\newcommand{\items}[1]{\glstext*{#1} & \glsdesc*{#1} [\glsuseri*{#1}] \\}

%Legend Environment
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{1cm} p{0.9 \textwidth}}
    \items{sym:deg}
    \items{sym:etadegr}
    \items{sym:tau}
\end{tabular}
```

## Question

I'd like to create a command which searches the previous `align` environment for elements of my `symbol glossary` and puts them into a legend (in this case tabular) environment. Does this already exist (didn't find anything)? And how would i realize this?
Not expecting a perfect solution but I have no clue how to do this.

An MWE to tinker with can be found here --> [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tairun/5575285)

€:
-Additional Information: Using miktex 2.9 and TechniXCenter 2 on Windows.
-Matches for the search could be done with the name key of the glossary entry

Comment: This is similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89107/glossary-per-chapter-or-section except you're using `equation` rather than `section`. (Is there a reason for using `align` rather than `equation`? If you're going to have multi-lined equations, that may make the solution harder.)

Comment: I fail to see how the other post could be of any help to me. There would be multiple `equations` per environment, hence the `align`. I don't think the glossaries package can provide a solution here (via glossariy styles).

Comment: This is not what you want, but if you are ready for special mark-up of the source like people do when thy want to index things, say `\x{\dot{D}}` rather than `\dot{D}`, `\x\tau` rather than `\tau`, etc... then a not too complicated solution would be easily feasible. (not by me, as I don't know anything about `glossary`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. It requires `xindy` rather than `makeindex`. If you really don't want to use `xindy`, it's possible to adjust the code, but it's more complicated.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[counter=alignglos,xindy]{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{slm}{sbl}{List of Symbols}

\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{0}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sym:deg}{  
type=symbols,  
name={\ensuremath{\dot{D}}},  
description={Prozentuale jährliche Abnahme des Wirkungsgrades},  
user1={\%/a},  
sort=deg  
}  

\newglossaryentry{sym:etadegr}{
type=symbols,
name={\ensuremath{\eta_{Deg,r}}},
description={Verbleibender Wirkungsgrad bezogen auf den
ursprünglichen Wirkungsgrad},
user1=\%,
sort=eta deg rest
}

\newglossaryentry{sym:tau}{
type=symbols,
name={\ensuremath{\tau}},
description={Lebenszyklus / Einsatzdauer des betrachteten Systems},
user1=a,
sort=tau
}

\newcommand{\items}[2]{\glstext*{#1} & #2 [\glsuseri*{#1}] \\}

\newglossarystyle{alignglos}%
{%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
   {\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm}p{0.9\textwidth}}}%
   {\end{tabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsXalignglosXglsnumberformat}[2]{##2}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimN}{,}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \edef\doifinlocation{\noexpand\ifinlocation{\thealignglos}{\expandafter\striprelax##5\endstriprelax}}%
    \doifinlocation
    {%
      \items{##1}{##3}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\ifinlocation}[3]{%
 \DTLifinlist{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
}

\def\striprelax\relax#1\endstriprelax{#1}


\newcounter{alignglos}

\newenvironment{alignglos}%
 {\stepcounter{alignglos}}%
 {%
   \printglossary[type=symbols,style=alignglos,title={}]
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{alignglos}
\begin{align}  
    \gls{sym:deg} &= \frac{1-\gls{sym:etadegr}}{\gls{sym:tau}}
\end{align}
\end{alignglos}

\begin{alignglos}
\begin{align}  
    \gls{sym:tau} &= \ldots
\end{align}
\end{alignglos}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Here's the code for use with `makeindex` instead of `xindy`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[counter=alignglos]{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{slm}{sbl}{List of Symbols}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sym:deg}{  
type=symbols,  
name={\ensuremath{\dot{D}}},  
description={Prozentuale jährliche Abnahme des Wirkungsgrades},  
user1={\%/a},  
sort=deg  
}  

\newglossaryentry{sym:etadegr}{
type=symbols,
name={\ensuremath{\eta_{Deg,r}}},
description={Verbleibender Wirkungsgrad bezogen auf den
ursprünglichen Wirkungsgrad},
user1=\%,
sort=eta deg rest
}

\newglossaryentry{sym:tau}{
type=symbols,
name={\ensuremath{\tau}},
description={Lebenszyklus / Einsatzdauer des betrachteten Systems},
user1=a,
sort=tau
}

\newcommand{\items}[2]{\glstext*{#1} & #2 [\glsuseri*{#1}] \\}

% clean up the format of the location list
\newcommand{\stripentrynumbers}[1]{%
  \striprelax#1\endstriprelax
}

\newglossarystyle{alignglos}%
{%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
   {\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm}p{0.9\textwidth}}}%
   {\end{tabular}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsnumberformat}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimR}{-}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimN}{,}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
  \let\glossaryentrynumbers\stripentrynumbers
    \edef\doifinloclist{\noexpand\ifinloclist{\thealignglos}{##5}}%
    \doifinloclist
    {%
      \items{##1}{##3}%
    }%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[1]{\glossaryentryfield}%
}

\newcommand{\ifinloclist}[3]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
     \let\dolistbreak\relax
     \doifinloc{#1}{#3}##1-\relax\endrange
     \dolistbreak
  }%
  \docsvlist{#2}%
}

\def\doifinloc#1#2#3-#4\endrange{%
   \ifx\relax#4\relax
     % just a number
     \ifnum#1=#3\relax
       #2%
       \let\dolistbreak\listbreak
     \fi
   \else
    \doifinrange{#1}{#2}#3-#4%
   \fi
}

\def\doifinrange#1#2#3-#4-\relax{%
  \ifnum#1=#3\relax
     #2%
     \let\dolistbreak\listbreak
  \else
    \ifnum#1=#4\relax
       #2%
       \let\dolistbreak\listbreak
    \else
      \ifnum#1>#3\relax
        \ifnum#1<#4\relax
          #2%
          \let\dolistbreak\listbreak
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\def\striprelax\relax\setentrycounter[]#1#2\endstriprelax{#2}


\newcounter{alignglos}

\newenvironment{alignglos}%
 {\stepcounter{alignglos}}%
 {%
   \printglossary[type=symbols,style=alignglos,title={}]
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{alignglos}
\begin{align}  
    \gls{sym:deg} &= \frac{1-\gls{sym:etadegr}}{\gls{sym:tau}}
\end{align}
\end{alignglos}

\begin{alignglos}
\begin{align}  
    \gls{sym:tau} &= \ldots
\end{align}
\end{alignglos}

\end{document}
```

Result for either method:

[image: Image of resulting document]

This will also work if you want to use `equation` instead of `align`. The code is adapted from [Glossary per chapter or section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89107/glossary-per-chapter-or-section). You just need to wrap your equations inside the `alignglos` environment.

**Notes:**

1. I've used `\ensuremath` instead of `$` so it doesn't matter if you are in or out of math mode when you use the glossary entry
2. I think `Deg` should probably be `\operatorname{Deg}` or `\mathrm{Deg}` (assuming it's not just `D` times `e` times `g`).

**Edit 2:**

I've modified the `alignglos` style so that it suppresses the group skip. I've also deferred `\listbreak` to the end of `\do`. If you have Perl installed, you can use the `makeglossaries` script to call `makeindex` or `xindy`, which will skip any empty glossaries. If you have Perl and Java installed, you can just run [`arara`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/arara.html) on the document and it will run all the commands listed in the `% arara:` directives. When you switch to linux, you should have Perl preinstalled and probably also the Java runtime environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I fail to get xindy to work on windows. I followed these instructions to the dot (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex). I suspect its the `.cnf` file. I tried modifying all the paths, did not help. I'm not sure to what extent I need to modify the command line parameter for xindy in order to work with the glossaries package either. And also why is your solution xindy specific? What would need to be changed in order to run on pure makeindex?

Comment: It's the ability to switch off the range formation (`\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{0}`) that makes it easier to do in `xindy`. To get it to work with `makeindex`, `\ifinlocation` would need to be modified so that it can check if a number lies within a given range (and detect if there is a range present). `\glsXalignglosXglsnumberformat` is also `xindy`-specific. I'll see if I can work out the modifications to make it work with `makeindex`.

Comment: I really don't mid using xindy at all (since I'm switching to linux only soon). I just don't know how to make it work. The glossaries documentation provides some help (chapter `Use xindy explicitly`). I tried to adapt the syntax for the command line to my TeXnicCenter setup, sadly with no succes.

Comment: I first struggled to get the `makeindex` version to work but turns out the problem was laying with TeXnicCenters post processing handler. I have defined 3 post processing jobs: glossary, acronyms and symbols. If the first two are empty you need to move the symbol job to the top or else the other ones won't get processed. I need to check if this holds true for `xindy` as well, but I need the other PC to check. Will report back later. One issue with this solution though: If you have `nogroupskip` set I get error `Incomplete \iftrue, all text was ignored after line ...` and `Missing } inserted`

Comment: Still no luck with xindy. What command do you use to compile the glossary with xindy if I may ask?

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'll stick with the makeindex version for now and tackle xindy after I finished writing my paper. Thanks again for helping me out and have a great day ;-)

Comment: I have now incorporated the solution in my thesis but it behaves somewhat differently than in the MWE. First thing: There is a warning saying: `name{alignglos.0} has been referenced bit does not exist`. Secondly the inserted legend is the whole symbol glossary rather than only the used symbols inside the `align` env. and lastly it messes with all the page numbers in the others glossaries. Another thing: If i use the `toc` option an empty line shows up in pdf bookmarks. The stared version of \printglossary produces `destination with the same indentifier`.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll have to modify the minimal example so that it reproduces those problems and post it as a new question. It sounds like you're using `hyperref` which complicates matters. The `alignglos` style will need to be modified to counteract the `toc` setting.

Comment: So I could fix the reference errors by changing the package order to `glossaries` `hyperlink` `cleverref` . The other issues persist. I have spent some time to create another MWE which reproduces described behaviour. It doesn't behave exactly as my big document but in similar fashion. As you suggested I will open a new question. Link will also be posted here.

Comment: Follow up: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114621/custom-glossary-environment-improvment