# abbreviation in latex of my university template

Tags: acronyms

My university provides a template which can be used for writing thesis.

In this template, there is a basic method to write the abbreviations in my thesis. Actually, this way is not suitable for me. I am looking for a way that allow me to do the abbreviation in each chapter.

Note: each chapter has a separate file.

This is the file code:

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Progress.tex
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 
\documentclass{ecsthesis}    % Use the progress Style

\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, boldline} %
\usepackage{cellspace}
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   % Location of your graphics files
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}   % Set to false for black/white printing
\input{Definitions}            % Include your abbreviations
\usepackage[sort]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}


 \usepackage{grffile}

\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}

%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title      {Here is the title}
\authors    {\texorpdfstring
             {\href{mailto:a@a.com}{Name}}
             {Name}
            }

\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}



\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Here is the abstract.
\end{abstract}




\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\listofsymbols{ll}{$w$ & The weight vector\\
    $E$ & The electric field}
\acknowledgements{ Thanks! }
%\dedicatory{To \dots}
\mainmatter
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\include{Introduction}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Thesis_references}
\end{document} 
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can see the list of the tables and figures, they don't ask me to write the lists manually.

i.e. for example I use for figure this code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=3.5cm 6.2cm .5cm  .5cm,clip,scale=0.12]{Figures/crystalline.pdf}
    \caption{Scheme of crystalline. }
    \label{fig:crystalline}
\end{figure}
```

Then, it is automatically added this figure to the list of figures. Can I do something like this for the abbreviations please?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the document class file?

Comment: Of course, this is the link ( http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/ )

Comment: I think, I finally understand what you want. Wouldn't packages like `nomencl`, `acro` or `glossaries` (or other similar packages) suit your needs. And if you mean by 'do the abbreviation in each chapter' creating a list of symbols per chapter you could look at this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123824/list-of-symbols-for-each-chapter Or have I mistaken your intentions?

Comment: I don't want to create a list of symbol per chapter, I want them all showing after the list of figures and tables.

Comment: Then still those packages mentioned above will allow you to create such a list.