# How to define index and multiple glossaries with the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, indexing

### Problem Statement

I would like to make an index with the courtesy of `glossaries` package. However, I received a message while using `makeglossaries`

> Warning: File 'document.idx' is empty. Have you used any entries defined in glossary 'index'?

I have defined the list of index through the type of index. While the glossary lists are successful (the sourced question was after for per chapter basis, while I adapted for per part basis), I could not do this for the list of  index.

### MWE

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,openright,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
 \usepackage[xindy,order=letter,nonumberlist,toc,nopostdot,nomain,nohypertypes={index}]{glossaries}
 \renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
 \newglossary{glossary1}{glossarypt01}{glossPt01}{Glossary for Part I} % Note: No front zeros
 \newcommand{\addgloss}[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{type=glossary\arabic{part},name=#1,description={#2}}}
 \newcommand{\addglossmath}[3]{\newglossaryentry{#3}{type=glossary\arabic{part},name=\ensuremath{#1},description={#2}}}
 % Code amdended from Ludovic C.@TeX.SE (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123824/list-of-symbols-for-each-chapter)
 \newcommand{\printpartglossary}{\glsaddall%
 \printglossary[type=glossary\arabic{part}]}
 \newglossary[ilg]{index}{ind}{idx}{\indexname}
 \newcommand{\newidx}[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}[type=index,name=#1,description=\nopostdesc]}
 \makeglossaries

 \begin{document}
 \part{Start}
 \chapter{Dummy Chapter}
 \addgloss{complex number}{A type of numbers in the form of $x\;+\;iy$.}
 \section{Complex (Number) Set is the Largest Numerical Set}

 Textbooks when introducing \addgloss{complex number} \newidx{complex number}, do list a set of equations and specify the largest set could not solve such equation. Hence we ought for a complex number. 

 \cleardoublepage
 \printpartglossary

 \printglossary[type=index]
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle problem is with the definition of `\newidx`:

```
 \newcommand{\newidx}[2]{\newglossaryentry{#1}[type=index,name=#1,description=\nopostdesc]}
```

Firstly, this uses the wrong syntax for `\newglossaryentry`. The key=value list should be in braces `{}` not square brackets. The second problem is that `\newidx` is defined here to have two arguments but you're only using it with one argument.

The other issue here is that you're only defining entries but not indexing them. This means that every time you do `\newidx{complex number}`, you're just defining the entry (storing it for later use). So the correct definition should be:

```
\newcommand{\newidx}[1]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{type=index,name=#1,description=\nopostdesc}% define it
  \glsadd{#1}% index it
}
```

A similar problem occurs with your other commands like `\addgloss` and `\addglossmath`. Each label (the first argument of `\newglossaryentry`) should be unique, but you have a label clash with two different entries both wanting to use the label `complex number`. However because you're defining your entries in the document instead of the preamble the safeguard that prevents this clash has been disabled, so the `complex number` label always refers to the first entry defined with that label. This clash can be overcome by enforcing a prefix in the definitions of your custom commands. For example:

```
\newcommand{\addgloss}[2]{%
 \newglossaryentry
 {gls\arabic{part}:#1}% label
 {type=glossary\arabic{part},name=#1,description={#2}}%
 \glsadd{gls\arabic{part}:#1}%
}

\newcommand{\newidx}[1]{%
 \newglossaryentry{idx:#1}{type=index,name={#1},description=\nopostdesc}%
 \glsadd{idx:#1}}
```

The other problem is that `\addgloss` is defined to take two arguments, but you've used it with only one argument in:

```
\addgloss{complex number} \newidx{complex number}
```

This means that it's taking `\newidx` as the second argument. Since `complex number` has already been defined with `\addgloss`, this does nothing and you're left with just `{complex number}`, which is why it looks as though the `\addgloss` seems to be working when actually it isn't. It would in fact be better to define:

```
\newcommand{\addgloss}[2]{%
 \newglossaryentry
 {gls\arabic{part}:#1}% label
 {type=glossary\arabic{part},name=#1,description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\refgloss}[1]{\gls{gls\arabic{part}:#1}}
```

Then use `\refgloss` to reference the entry. Like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[xindy,order=letter,nonumberlist,toc,nopostdot,
 nomain,nohypertypes={index},
]{glossaries}

\newglossary{glossary1}{glossarypt01}{glossPt01}{Glossary for Part I}
\newglossary[ilg]{index}{ind}{idx}{\indexname}

\newcommand{\printpartglossary}{\glsaddall%
\printglossary[type=glossary\arabic{part}]}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\addgloss}[2]{%
 \newglossaryentry
 {gls\arabic{part}:#1}% label
 {type=glossary\arabic{part},name=#1,description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\refgloss}[1]{\gls{gls\arabic{part}:#1}}

\newcommand{\addglossmath}[3]{%
 \newglossaryentry{#3}{type=glossary\arabic{part},name=\ensuremath{#1},description={#2}}}

\newcommand{\newidx}[1]{%
 \newglossaryentry{idx:#1}{type=index,name={#1},description=\nopostdesc}%
 \glsadd{idx:#1}}


\begin{document}
\part{Start}
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}
\addgloss{complex number}{A type of numbers in the form of $x\;+\;iy$.}
\section{Complex (Number) Set is the Largest Numerical Set}

Textbooks when introducing \refgloss{complex number}\newidx{complex number}, do list a set of equations and specify the largest set could not solve such equation. Hence we ought for a complex number. 

\cleardoublepage
\printpartglossary

\printglossary[type=index]
\end{document}
```

The principle behind `glossaries` is that you first define your entries and then reference them in the document. (Think of it in terms of a bibliography where you store the data in a separate file and reference it in the document.) On the fly definitions within the document can cause problems, but these can be reduced by extending the `glossaries` package with `glossaries-extra` and use the `docdef=restricted` package option. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,openright,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[xindy,order=letter,nonumberlist,
 nomain,nohypertypes={index},
 docdef=restricted
]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary{glossary1}{glossarypt01}{glossPt01}{Glossary for Part I} % Note: No front zeros
\newglossary[ilg]{index}{ind}{idx}{\indexname}

\newcommand{\printpartglossary}{\glsaddall%
\printglossary[type=glossary\arabic{part}]}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\addgloss}[2]{%
 \newglossaryentry
 {gls\arabic{part}:#1}% label
 {type=glossary\arabic{part},name=#1,description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\refgloss}[1]{\gls{gls\arabic{part}:#1}}

\newcommand{\addglossmath}[3]{%
 \newglossaryentry{#3}{type=glossary\arabic{part},name=\ensuremath{#1},description={#2}}}

\newcommand{\newidx}[1]{%
 \ifglsentryexists{idx:#1}%
 {}% already defined
 {%
   \newglossaryentry{idx:#1}{type=index,name={#1},description=\nopostdesc}%
 }%
 \glsadd{idx:#1}}


\begin{document}
\part{Start}
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}
\addgloss{complex number}{A type of numbers in the form of $x\;+\;iy$.}
\section{Complex (Number) Set is the Largest Numerical Set}

Textbooks when introducing \refgloss{complex number}\newidx{complex number}, do list a set of equations and specify the largest set could not solve such equation. Hence we ought for a complex number. 

\cleardoublepage
\printpartglossary

\printglossary[type=index]
\end{document}
```

*Edit:* There's no need for `\cleardoublepage` here as `\printglossary` (which is used in the definition of `\printpartglossary`) already issues a clear double page since it starts with `\chapter*` when used with the `scrbook` class. Also, the `\glsaddall` within `\printpartglossary` will index *all* defined entries at that point (including those defined in previous parts). It's redundant to keep doing this for every part of the book, and it may cause some odd behaviour.

Incidentally, you might want to switch on the number list for the index, as there doesn't seem much point in having an index without it. You might also want to change to a more appropriate style for the index (e.g `mcolindex`) and suppress the bold font for the index entries.

Amended MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude,openright,chapterprefix=on,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[xindy,order=letter,
 stylemods={mcols},% load glossary-mcols.sty
 nomain,nohypertypes={index},
 docdef=restricted
]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossary{glossary1}{glossarypt01}{glossPt01}{Glossary for Part I}
\newglossary[ilg]{index}{ind}{idx}{\indexname}

% Just suppress numberlists for the "part" glossaries
\newcommand{\printpartglossary}{%
  \printglossary[nonumberlist,type=glossary\arabic{part}]}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\addgloss}[2]{%
 \newglossaryentry
 {gls\arabic{part}:#1}% label
 {type=glossary\arabic{part},name=#1,description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand*{\refgloss}[1]{\gls{gls\arabic{part}:#1}}

\newcommand{\addglossmath}[3]{%
 \newglossaryentry{#3}{type=glossary\arabic{part},name=\ensuremath{#1},description={#2}}}

\newcommand{\newidx}[1]{%
 \ifglsentryexists{idx:#1}%
 {}% already defined
 {%
   \newglossaryentry{idx:#1}{type=index,name={#1},description=\nopostdesc}%
 }%
 \glsadd{idx:#1}}


\begin{document}
\part{Start}
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}
\addgloss{complex number}{A type of numbers in the form of $x\;+\;iy$.}
\section{Complex (Number) Set is the Largest Numerical Set}

Textbooks when introducing \refgloss{complex number}\newidx{complex number}, do list a set of equations and specify the largest set could not solve such equation. Hence we ought for a complex number. 

\printpartglossary

\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}% remove bold font in mcolindex style
\printglossary[type=index,style=mcolindex]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dr Talbot. I remember that you are the author of these packages, while your answer is very comprehensive and useful.

Comment: However, I have an exam on Monday. While this is an important exam and I really want to spend time one reading your answer, may I reply again at Monday afternoon (at your time)?

Comment: @SHY.John Yes, the site should notify me if you ping me in a comment. Good luck with your exam.

Comment: I end up detour from my study to read your answer. But I caught a cold so I slept straight away after I gave a tick mark. Now I am feeling better.

Comment: After a while of using this code, the code produces two extra pages before the glossary/ index and an extra entry referred to this last page. I tested the code provided and the MWE could replicate the same issue.

Comment: At the moment I am seeking for appending a code to the MWE. This code is about automatically generating both glossary and index entry when calling \refgloss. While keeping the existing \newidx iff I have index entries that does not put into glossary. Is my direction right, Dr Talbot (@nicola-talbot)?

Comment: @SHY.John The extra pages are caused by `\cleardoublepage`. There's no need for that command. (It was in your original MWE and I didn't think to remove it from mine.) You might also be getting some interference from the `\glsaddall` in the definition of `\printpartglossary`. I can't see why that's needed there.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Dr Talbot (@nicola-talbot). May you amend your code in your response?

Comment: I also feel like I am half awake when I am writing the code for `\printpartglossary`...

Comment: @SHY.John I've edited my answer.