# Nomenclature per chapter

Tags: chapters, nomenclature, nomencl

I would like add a nomenclature at the end of each chapter of my dissertation, including the parameters of that chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Introduction 1}
Only $a$ will be discussed in this chapter. So, i do not need $N$ in the nomenclature. Besides I would like to have the nomenclature as a non numbered section (not a chapter).
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\printnomenclature

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{Introduction 2}
Only $N$ will be discussed in this chapter. So, i do not need $a$ in the nomenclature. Besides I would like to have the nomenclature as a non numbered section (not a chapter).
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Dear All, any idea?
I appreciate your help

Comment: Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123824/list-of-symbols-for-each-chapter  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121952/notation-table-in-each-chapter-part for advices and a possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it "manually" with the other nomenclature package: "nomentbl". You have to configure the tex compiler. I used Texstudio so I add an user command in:

Options > Configure Texstudio > Build > User commands then put these command in

makeindex -s nomentbl.ist -o %.nls %.nlo
[image]
Normally, you have to do the following procedure to have nomenclature:

Compile > Make index > Recompile

The principle is the same: when you run a make index, Latex will generate an .nls file. Next time you compile, the nomenclature will appear.

So instead of run a second compile, all you need is create a file name *nomen_chap0x* then you copy the content in the .nls file into the *nomen_chap0x* then you put the command : \input{nomen_chap0x}. When you compile, the nomenclature will appear in the section.

The important thing is you have to delete the .nls file and comment all of nomenclature in the chapter to avoid the same nomenclature's appearance in the next chapter.

In the second chapter, you have to create another nomenclature, used only for this chapter, and you repeat the procedure above

Her an mwe for what I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathtools}    % math formulations
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[intoc,noprefix]{nomentbl}
    \makeatletter % to put nomenclature in the section range of the TOC
    \def\thenomenclature{%
        \section*{\nomname}
        \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi%
        \nompreamble
        \list{}{%
            \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \itemsep\nomitemsep
            \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
    \makeatother
    \makenomenclature

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\chapter{blabla1}
\section{Example 01}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J_i} =  - {D_i}\left( {\nabla} {c_i} + \dfrac{{{z_i}F}}{{RT}}{c_i} {\nabla} \varphi  \right)
\label{eq505}
\end{equation}
where $ \mathbf{J_i} $ is the ion flux, $ D_i $ is the bulk diffusion coefficient of the ionic species, $ F $ is the Faraday constant, $ R $ is the universal gas constant and $ T $ is the temperature

\nomenclature[A]{$ D_{i} $}{Bulk diffusion coefficient of the species}{\si{\square\m / \s}}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ F $}{Faraday constant}{\si{\coulomb / \mole}}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ R $}{ Universal gas constant}{\si{\J / \kelvin \mole}}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ T $}{Temperature}{\si{\kelvin}}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ z $}{Charge number of the ionic species }{}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ J $}{ Flux of the ionic species}{\si{\mole / \m^2 \s}}{}
\nomenclature[G]{$ \varphi $}{Total electric potential}{\si{\volt}}{}
\input{nomen_chap1}
\chapter{blabla2}
\section{Example 02}
\lipsum[1]
The Ohm's law:
\begin{equation}
R_{s}= \frac{U}{I}
\end{equation}
where $ R_s $ is the resistance (\si{\ohm}), $ U $ is the voltage (\si{\volt}) and $ I $ is the electric current (\si{\ampere})
\nomenclature[A]{$ R_s $}{Resistance}{\si{\ohm}}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ U $}{Voltage}{\si{\volt}}{}
\nomenclature[A]{$ I $}{Electric current}{\si{\ampere}}{}
\input{nomen_chap2}
\end{document}
```

Here is the results:

[image]

I also put the entire **mwe folder** fmi:
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbepk2uzg4xsw0o/mwe.zip?dl=0)