# Is there a way to divide bibliography, indexes in two volumes?

Tags: biblatex, indexing, titletoc

I'm working on a big thesis, divided in two volumes (but one pdf), which are sequentially numbered.
Main TOC and TOCs for volumes are made using `titletoc` package:

```
\startcontents[main]
.....
\entcontents[main]
```

I'm interested is there a way to divide bibliography (`biblatex`) and indexes(`glossaries`), so bibliography for Volume 1 will be put after Volume 1 main text and respectively bibliography for Volume 2 after main text of Volume 2. The same question I'm addressing regarding indexes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answers the bibliography part. For the glossary part take a look at [Glossary per chapter or section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89107/27635).

Supposing your two volumes are two `\part`s, add the option `refsection=part` when loading `biblatex` and issue

```
\printbibliography[section=1]
```

at the end of the first volume and

```
\printbibliography[section=2]
```

at the end of the second volume.

If your volumes don't correspond to `\part`s but to something else, change the option accordingly.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[refsection=part,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\part{Volume I}

\chapter{Test}
\cite{aksin}

\chapter{Test}
\cite{angenendt}

\printbibliography[section=1]

\part{Volume II}

\chapter{Test}
\cite{aksin}

\chapter{Test}
\cite{bertram}

\printbibliography[section=2]

\end{document}
```

Output (1st bibliography)

[image]

Output (2nd bibliography)

[image]

Comment: could you suggest how to do the same with indexes?

Comment: @saldenisov As I said in the answer, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89107/27635. It can only be done with Xindy and I don't have it installed, so I can't test it.