# Glossaries per chapter not produced during compile

Tags: glossaries, subdividing, xindy

I am trying to make glossaries per chapter for my book. This per chapter design for the glossary is tested from this [answer at TEX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325434/glossary-per-chapter-not-by-section). But I am not able to print the glossary at the end of each chapter separately even the program runs but generates only the expanded version of the glossary every time.

Here is a MWE as per answer from [earlier post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325434/glossary-per-chapter-not-by-section).

```
\documentclass{book}% I am trying it for book
\usepackage{datatool-base}
\usepackage[counter=chapter,xindy,section=section]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{0}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{E}{name={\ensuremath{E}},description={energy}}
\newglossaryentry{m}{name={\ensuremath{m}},description={mass}}
\newglossaryentry{c}{name={\ensuremath{c}},description={speed of light}}
\newglossaryentry{v}{name={\ensuremath{v}},description=velocity}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}%
{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\striprelax##1\endstriprelax}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat}[2]{##2}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimR}{,}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \edef\doifinlocation{\noexpand\ifinlocation{\thechapter}{##2}}%
    \doifinlocation
    {%
      \item \glossentryname{##1} \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ifinlocation}[3]{%
 \DTLifinlist{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
}
\def\striprelax\relax#1\endstriprelax{#1}
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\printglossary
\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \gls{m}\cdot \gls{c}^2
\end{equation}
\glsresetall 
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\printglossary
\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \frac{\gls{m}\gls{v}^2}{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you used `makeindex` or `makeglossaries` during the compile? for `glossaries` your make routine should be: `pdflatex` -> `makeglossaries` -> 2x `pdflatex` -> `<pdfviewer>`

Comment: @naphaneal 2 , I am using WinEdt editor and it auto compile in this mode `pdflatex > Bibtex > Makeindex > MakeGlossary > pdflatex > pdfviewer`. The output glossary is not printed instead where I have use d`\gls{E} its simply print E and not the glossary.

Comment: you don't need `makeindex` in the compile run. just use `makeglossaries`. I ran your code with the routine in my last comment. it worked fine.

Comment: I am receiving these warning `pdfTeX warning (dest): name{glo:m} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`                              
    Further on simply running of MakeGlossary gives following messages `Command Line:   makeindex.exe -s "mainbook.ist" -t "mainbook.glg" -o "mainbook.gls" "mainbook.glo"` `Index style file mainbook.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]`

Comment: what basic latex system are you using? (I tried your code with TL 2018, TeXstudio 2.12.10 and it worked smoothly.) Maybe there's something wrong with your version of WinEdt, but I'm the wrong person to ask. Do try if you can run the compile commands from the command line interface for Windows.

Comment: @naphaneal, I am using mIkTeX 2.9 , when I ran Make glossaries following message are displayed. Can you help in identifying the possible error. `This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6730 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./mainbook.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file mainbook.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 5 rejected).
Nothing written in mainbook.gls.
Transcript written in mainbook.glg.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81537/discussion-between-deb-bijan-and-naphaneal).

Comment: the setup is messed up. the path to `makeglossaries` should point to: `C:\MiKTeX\texmf\scripts\glossaries`. (adapt to your situation.) correct, try and rerun. if that does not help. reinstall MiKTeX. I think, there went something wrong during installation.