# Separate list of abbreviations/acronyms for each chapter in book with `glossaries` package

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I'm trying to generate a list of abbreviations/acronyms separately for each chapter in a book using the `glossaries` package and `xindy`. Any abbreviation can appear in any chapter.

Using Nicola Talbot's suggestions on how this works for [chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325566) and [sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89501/81540) as a starting point, I **cannot make this work for more than two chapters**.

The following MWE does not give the correct output: in Chapter 2, *mass* is not listed in the glossary, even though `\gls{m}` is used in the equation. The expected behaviour would be for *mass* to be included in the glossary.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{datatool-base}
\usepackage[counter=chapter,xindy,section=section]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{0}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{E}{name={\ensuremath{E}},description={energy}}
\newglossaryentry{m}{name={\ensuremath{m}},description={mass}}
\newglossaryentry{c}{name={\ensuremath{c}},description={speed of light}}
\newglossaryentry{v}{name={\ensuremath{v}},description=velocity}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}%
{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\striprelax##1\endstriprelax}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat}[2]{##2}%
  \renewcommand*{\delimR}{,}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \edef\doifinlocation{\noexpand\ifinlocation{\thechapter}{##2}}%
    \doifinlocation
    {%
      \item \glossentryname{##1} \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ifinlocation}[3]{%
 \DTLifinlist{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
}
\def\striprelax\relax#1\endstriprelax{#1}
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\printglossary
\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \gls{m}\cdot \gls{c}^2
\end{equation}
\glsresetall
\chapter{Another Chapter (2)}
\printglossary
\begin{equation}
\gls{E} = \frac{\gls{m}\gls{v}^2}{2}
\end{equation}

\glsresetall
\chapter{Yet another Chapter (3)}
\printglossary
\begin{equation}
\gls{m}\gls{v}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Correct list of abbreviations for Chapter 1]
[image: Incorrect list of abbreviations for Chapter 2]
[image: Correct list of abbreviations for Chapter 3]

**If `\gls{m}` is removed from Chapter 3**, the list of abbreviations appears correctly for Chapter 2.

```
\begin{equation}
\gls{v}
\end{equation}
```

The difference between the outputs appears to originate in the `.gls` file. In the MWE's `.gls` file, the relevant lines are:

```
\glossentry{m}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat{}{1}\delimR 
\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat{}{3}}}\glsgroupskip
```

Changing this manually to include chapter 2 and re-running LaTeX on the MWE creates the right result.

```
\glossentry{m}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat{}{1}\delimR 
\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat{}{2}\delimR 
\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat{}{3}}}\glsgroupskip
```

How can the correct output be generated automatically rather than by messing with the `.gls` file?