# Glossary per chapter for unnumbered chapters

Tags: chapters, glossaries

I have a document that consists of sub-documents which are organized as chapters. These chapters have no numbers because the chapter titles are the titles of the sub-documents. Each chapter has its own pagenumbering, toc, etc. I want to include one glossary per chapter that contains all acronyms used in this chapter and only those used.

Using the method that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325434/glossary-per-chapter-not-by-section), this should be possible. Unfortunately this seems to work only for numbered chapters as this number (`\thechapter`) is used in the style definition (as far as I understand the code). Is there a way to use a hidden chapter number or ID for referencing the glossary entries?

Many thanks in advance

Chris

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}

\usepackage{datatool-base}
\usepackage[counter=chapter,xindy,section=section]{glossaries}

\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{0}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{E}{name={\ensuremath{E}},description={energy}}
\newglossaryentry{m}{name={\ensuremath{m}},description={mass}}
\newglossaryentry{c}{name={\ensuremath{c}},description={speed of light}}
\newglossaryentry{v}{name={\ensuremath{v}},description=velocity}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}%
{%
    \setglossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\striprelax##1\endstriprelax}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsXchapterXglsnumberformat}[2]{##2}%
    \renewcommand*{\delimR}{,}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \edef\doifinlocation{\noexpand\ifinlocation{\thechapter}{##2}}%
        \doifinlocation
        {%
            \item \glossentryname{##1} \glossentrydesc{##1}%
        }%
    }%
}
\newcommand{\ifinlocation}[3]{%
    \DTLifinlist{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
}
\def\striprelax\relax#1\endstriprelax{#1}
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Sample Chapter}
    \printglossary
    \begin{equation}
        \gls{E} = \gls{m}\cdot \gls{c}^2
    \end{equation}

    \glsresetall 
    \chapter*{Another Chapter}
    \printglossary
    \begin{equation}
        \gls{E} = \frac{\gls{m}\gls{v}^2}{2}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried the code  fo https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325566/161015 using   `\chapter*{Sample Chapter}` and  `\chapter*{Another Chapter}` and got the the glossary by chapter. Perhaps you should include a MWE that reproduce your result.

Comment: I added the sample code above. When using ```\chapter``` I get the correct result. ```\chapter*``` (with asterisk) gives one glossary per chapter, too. But in both glossaries are ALL symbols listed even if they are not referred in the corresponding chapter.