# Automatic creation of own tocs

Tags: table-of-contents

Dear TeX(stackexchange) community, I'm trying to create automatically my own TOCs: using `\keyword` command I define the entries of my own toc list so that each belonging to same chapter will be printed at beginning of chapter using `\listofkeywords`.

There is a problem for first chapter: no .key1 file created and no toc printed. That's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,fleqn]{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\usepackage[compact,toctitles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\huge}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:\ }{0pt}{\huge}[\addtocounter{cherrychapter}{1}]
\title{H\&R}
%%% COUNTERS
\newcounter{cherrychapter}%[chapte]
\setcounter{cherrychapter}{0}
\newcommand\keyword[1]{%
\noindent%
{#1}%
\phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is noy used
\thecherrychapter\thechapter\addcontentsline{key-\thecherrychapter}{figure}{#1}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listkeywordsname{KEYWORDS}
\newcommand\listofkeywords{%
\thecherrychapter\thechapter
\section*{\listkeywordsname}\@starttoc{key-\thecherrychapter}
\thecherrychapter\thechapter}
\makeatother
\begin{document}%BEGIN
\maketitle
\tableofcontents*
\part{A}
\chapter{aa}
\listofkeywords
\keyword{bb}
\section{aaa}
\keyword{bbb}
\subsection{aaaa}
\keyword{bbbb}
\chapter{cc}
\listofkeywords
\keyword{dd}
\section{ccc}
\keyword{ddd}
\subsection{cccc}
\keyword{dddd}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for aid.
Best regards.

Comment: Why use `\addcontentsline`? Are you willing to write your keywords to a file and read that back in?

Comment: I don't get this too. The keywords are not sorted in the output

Comment: The issue depends on the fact that `memoir` redefines the internal `\@starttoc`. I think a more robust solution will be provided by the package `glossaries` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89107/glossary-per-chapter-or-section

Comment: The usage of `titletoc` and `memoir`'s emulation of `tocloft` etc. features is also doubtful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The costepping of `cherrychapter` can be done with `xassoccnt`, provided, this auxiliary counter is needed at all.

The main issue is that `memoir` does a redefinition of `\@starttoc`. One possible solution is to store the original LaTeX core definition to `\@starttocorig` before `\documentclass` and use that version instead of `\@starttoc`.

For more than one chapter it will report any number but the last one to be not existing. This looks like an expansion issue, actually, since `memoir`'s version of `\@starttoc` tries to write to generate the file handle at the end of the document and opens the relevant file then, so `#1` expands to the wrong chapter number.

```
\makeatletter
\let\@starttocorig\@starttoc
\makeatother

\documentclass[oneside,11pt,fleqn]{memoir}

\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\newcounter{cherrychapter}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{cherrychapter}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\usepackage[compact,toctitles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\huge}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:\ }{0pt}{\huge}%
\title{H\&R}
\newcommand\keyword[1]{%
  \noindent%
  {#1}%
  \phantomsection% comment out if hyperref is not used
  \addcontentsline{key-\thecherrychapter}{figure}{#1}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofkeywordsbasic}{%
  \@starttocorig{key-\thecherrychapter}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\listkeywordsname{KEYWORDS}
\newcommand\listofkeywords{%
  \section*{\listkeywordsname}\listofkeywordsbasic
}



\begin{document}%BEGIN
\maketitle
\tableofcontents*
\part{A}
\chapter{aa}
\listofkeywords
\keyword{bb}
\section{aaa}
\keyword{bbb}
\subsection{aaaa}
\keyword{bbbb}
\chapter{cc}
\listofkeywords
\keyword{dd}
\section{ccc}
\keyword{ddd}
\subsection{cccc}
\keyword{dddd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained the internal command `\@starttoc` is redefined by `memoir`. The redefinition of the command `\@starttoc` is used to define the user command `\newlistof`.

To use the possibilities of `\newlistof` you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt,fleqn]{memoir}

\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\newcounter{cherrychapter}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{chapter}{cherrychapter}

\newcommand\keyword[1]{#1\phantomsection\addcontentsline{key-\thecherrychapter}{figure}{#1}}

\providecommand\listofkeywords{}
\newcommand\listkeywordsname{KEYWORDS}
\renewcommand\memendofchapterhook{
  \edef\x{\noexpand\newlistof{listofkeywords}{key-\thecherrychapter}{\listkeywordsname}}\x%
}


\begin{document}%BEGIN
\chapter{aa}
\listofkeywords

\keyword{bb}
\section{aaa}
\keyword{bbb}
\subsection{aaaa}
\keyword{bbbb}

\chapter{cc}
\listofkeywords

\keyword{dd}
\section{ccc}
\keyword{ddd}
\subsection{cccc}
\keyword{dddd}

\chapter{dd}
\listofkeywords

\keyword{ee}
\section{eee}
\keyword{eee}
\subsection{eeee}
\keyword{eeeee}
\end{document}
```